# Open another UI dialog from allready opened one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi I open UI dialog this way:

```
function openDialog(page, heightPar, title) {

             var $dialog1 = jQuery('#dialog');
             $dialog1.load('../EMS/' + page);
             $dialog1.dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,
                 title: title, //Add New Contact Personel
                 modal: true,
                 height: heightPar,
                 width: 450,
                 show: 'puff',
                 hide: 'puff',
                 close: function (event, ui) {
                     $dialog1.html('');
                     $dialog1.dialog('destroy');
                     //          window.location.reload();

                 }
             });
             $dialog1.dialog('open');


         }
```

and on this dialog i have another copy of this function but with main variable name dialog2, so what i want is to open another dialog from one opened before, is that possible? cos now if i open second it replease the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the dialog in the div with id #dialog, so if your other function also creates the dialog in #dialog it will be replaced,

Try creating the other dialog in a new div #dialog2.

Comment: yee u r right i just saw it before read it, but thank , this is the answer :)